# Select based on group membership

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have two tables `t` and `o`. I want to select all the rows of `t` in which `t.feature = o.feature` (ergo first two rows).

In addition, I also want to select all the rows whose `t.grouping` = `t.grouping` of the previously selected rows. In this case `t.grouping` 1, 2 ergo rows `('E', 1)`, `('F', 2)` and `('G', 1)`. What is the most elegant way of achieving this?

```
CREATE TABLE t
(   feature      VARCHAR,
    grouping            BIGINT
);

INSERT INTO t (feature, grouping)
VALUES ('A', 1), 
        ('B', 2),
        ('C', 5), 
        ('D', 4),
        ('E', 1), 
        ('F', 2),
        ('G', 1);
        
        
CREATE TABLE o
(   feature VARCHAR
);

INSERT INTO o (feature)
VALUES ('A'),
       ('B');
```

Comment: The first issue is your concept of `order`.  Rows in tables have no implied or explicit `order`, unless you (or your DB implementation) add a column or columns for that purpose.  What data in your rows are you using to determine `order`?  Some databases do have an accessible rowid (or the like) which can be used for this.

Comment: Please add you deisred output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly try this...

```
with cte as 
(select grouping from t inner join o on t.feature=o.feature)
select t.* 
from t 
inner join cte on t.grouping=cte.grouping
```

or

```
select 
* 
from t 
where grouping in 
(select grouping from t inner join o on t.feature=o.feature )
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_9.6&fiddle=96493b95f678090416128062af091ffa)